# MySQL execute SELECT based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

How to use CASE appropriately for executing SELECT query based on user input ?

On executing following query :

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN user_input_variable = 'y' THEN        
    (SELECT * FROM table_foo WHERE bar = '6f322766-0ec0-4d24-840f-c857a82a6efe')        

    ELSE
    (SELECT 0)
     END
```

If the user has selected 'y' then it should return records from the table, else it should return an empty result set.

I am getting error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: The sub-query must return not more than 1 column. Do a UNION ALL instead of using a case expression.

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your query.  In terms of pseudo code, it appears that you would always just be executing the `SELECT * FROM table_foo`.

Comment: What's the parameter? What's the expected output when the parameter has one value and the other value(s)?

Comment: The second query `SELECT 0` returns a different number of columns than the fist one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I have updated the question. If the user has selected 'y' then it should return records from the table, else it should return an empty result set.

Comment: @NitinKabra . . . The expression cannot be represented as a single query, because the two queries are returning different numbers of columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... I have been using this query (MySQL 5.6.2) for a while, it suddenly stopped working (MySQL 8.0), CASE WHEN '{3}' = 'y' THEN SELECT * FROM transaction_bank_allocation WHERE company_code = '{0}' AND r_trans_id = {1}; ELSE SELECT 3 AS no_bank_alloc_selected; END CASE;

Answer (score 4):

The sub-query must return not more than 1 column. Do a UNION ALL instead.

Note that the number of columns must be the same, that's why you need to select null's in the second select.

```
SELECT * FROM table_foo WHERE bar = '6f322766-0ec0-4d24-840f-c857a82a6efe')
    and user_input_variable = 'y' 
union all     
SELECT 0, null, null... where user_input_variable <> 'y'
```

Comment: Beat me to it +1, but I think you've been sitting on this longer than I have :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I started writing this minutes ago, but had to do some other stuff before finishing it.

Comment: I have been using this query (MySQL 5.6.2) for a while, it suddenly stopped working (MySQL 8.0), 

CASE WHEN '{3}' = 'y' THEN 
 
  SELECT * FROM transaction_bank_allocation WHERE company_code = '{0}' AND r_trans_id = {1};
 ELSE 
  SELECT 3 AS no_bank_alloc_selected;
 END CASE;

Comment: Also, there are multiple when cases in real situation, where there are joins based on the user input

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IF condition also.

```
IF user_input_variable = 'y'
    SELECT * FROM table_foo WHERE bar = '6f322766-0ec0-4d24-840f-c857a82a6efe')
```